# How do I perform CRUD operations on the current authenticated users account information, in Blazor WASM?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

In Blazor WASM, I can get the current user logged in and I can get their email address etc. using:

```
[Inject] AuthenticationStateProvider authStateProvider { get; set; }

var user = authStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync().Result.User;
```

But I don't know how to use the currently authenticated user, to create a secure page where they can edit information such as their first name, last name, phone number etc.

Basically, I need a way to update the AspNetUsers table that is generated and any information in there for the current user. It needs to be secure too, so not just getting the info by using the email address for example.

Similar to how the template server side page allows but I want the user to do it via a Blazor component / page and then I'll have API endpoints to get and update the info.

More information: Blazor WASM Project, Configured for HTTPS, ASP.NET Core Hosted, PWA, Individual Accounts Authentication Type.

The below is an example of what I'd like to do but on the server side of the Blazor app template:
[image]

Comment: You will need to create an endpoint on your server-side to update these informations. In the client you don't have access to such secure stuff, it's the same as if you would create your client with plain old javascript.

Comment: @Simon Maybe I should edit my question to be more clear. I know that I will need to create endpoints to perform the operations. That is fine. 
For example, in my app I have Journal entries. I display a list of them and when the user clicks on one, I can pass the JournalEntry's Id to the HttpGet method and return information using that Id... 
What is the equivalent of the JournalEntry Id that I pass to the endpoint to get the User's Information? Sorry, I'm clueless here but hopefully I can learn.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then you don't really pass the user's id yourself to the backend controller. Instead you simply add an `[Authorize]` on the backend controller method where you want to update the user data. You will need to pass the authorization header (or cookie depending on what auth method you are using) to the backend when you make any authenticated request. See [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-5.0) for more info on how to do that exactly.